# How to make partitioning in existing mysql table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table called tbl_rtdata. I was dropped the all partitions in that table and create  the new partition in the below manner.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_rtdata  PARTITION BY RANGE (Month(fld_date))

SUBPARTITION BY HASH (Day(fld_date)) SUBPARTITIONS 12(   
PARTITION Apr_0 VALUES LESS THAN (2012-05-01),
PARTITION May_1 VALUES LESS THAN (2012-06-01),    
PARTITION Jun_2 VALUES LESS THAN (2012-07-01),  
PARTITION Jul_3 VALUES LESS THAN (2012-08-01),
PARTITION Aug_4 VALUES LESS THAN (2012-09-01),
PARTITION Sep_5 VALUES LESS THAN (2012-10-01),
PARTITION Oct_6 VALUES LESS THAN (2012-11-01),  
PARTITION Nov_7 VALUES LESS THAN (2012-12-01),
PARTITION Dec_8 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE );
```

But I got an Error : 
`VALUES LESS THAN value must be strictly increasing for each partition.`

If I remove the subpartition in query it shows the error VALUES value for partition 'Apr_0' must have type INT

What I should do to recover from this ?

Comment: which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer which is very simple, use to_days function

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_rtdata  PARTITION BY RANGE (Month(fld_date))
(   
PARTITION p_Apr VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-05-01')),
PARTITION p_May VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-06-01')), 
PARTITION p_Jun VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-07-01')),  
PARTITION p_Jul VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-08-01')),
PARTITION p_Aug VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-09-01')),
PARTITION p_Sep VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-10-01')),
PARTITION p_Oct VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-11-01')),  
PARTITION p_Nov VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-12-01')),
PARTITION p_Dec VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE );
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works as intended? By what I can see, All of the values would (almost) always be put in `p_Apr` since `Month(fld_date)` would always return a value that is less than `TO_DAYS('2012-05-01')`

Comment: It should be `BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(fld_date))`.

Comment: If you will be dropping old partitions, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint for details on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not supported in `MySQL < 5.5`
try this: Manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html)

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_rtdata PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (fld_date) (
  PARTITION Apr_0 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-05-01'),
  PARTITION May_1 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-06-01'),
  PARTITION Dec_8 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
  );
```

Comment: It's returning Error Code: 1697. VALUES value for partition 'Apr_0' must have type INT